# java decrease time between mouseMotionListener intervals

Tags: java, swing, mousemotionlistener

I want to create a simple drawing programm in java which currently only draws a line using `Graphics.fillOval()` and a `mouseMotionListener()`. The problem is, that if you move the mouse quickly the line gets less precise and the ovals (circles in this case) spread apart.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Drawing 
{
     private JFrame window;
     private Graphics g;
     public Drawing()
     {
        window=new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Paint_window");
        window.setSize(1000,700);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g=window.getGraphics();
        window.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                {
                 if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)
                {
                        g.fillOval((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY(),10,10);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Is there a way of improving this or a better way to this?

Comment: *"decrease time between mouseMotionListener intervals"* I don't think that can be done short of native (i.e. **not** Java) code. Why not retain the last mouse position reported, then if the distance to the new position is greater than a defined amount, draw ovals *along the line* separating the two points?

Comment: What you're asking is called an XY problem. You ask for the solution of X while the actual problem is Y and fixing Y also fixes X. In your case, you want to ask how to 'connect the dots'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g=window.getGraphics();
```

First of all you should not be using getGraphics() of a component. Any painting you do will only be temporary and will be erased the first time Swing determines the component needs to be repainted. In you above example just try resizing the frame to see this.

The proper way to do custom painting is to override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel and add the panel to the frame. See [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

> The problem is, that if you move the mouse quickly the line gets less precise and the ovals (circles in this case) spread apart

You will not be able to have an event generated for every pixel the mouse moves.

Instead you need to be able to "draw a line" between consecutive points generated as you drag the mouse.

So you need to store each point in an ArrayList and in the custom painting code iterate through all the points and draw a line.

A basic example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel
{
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> previous = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
    private ArrayList<Point> current = new ArrayList<Point>();
    private BasicStroke basicStroke;

    public DrawingPanel(int strokeSize)
    {
        basicStroke = new BasicStroke(strokeSize, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);

        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                current.add( new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()) );
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {
                current.add( new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()) );
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (current.size() > 1)
                {
                    previous.add( current );
                }

                current = new ArrayList<Point>();
            }
        };

        addMouseMotionListener( ma );
        addMouseListener( ma );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke( basicStroke );

        //  Paint lines from previous drags

        for (int i = 0; i < previous.size(); i++)
        {
            drawLines(g, previous.get(i));
        }

        //  Paint line from current drag

        drawLines(g, current);
    }

    private void drawLines(Graphics g, ArrayList<Point> points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            int x = (int) points.get(i).getX();
            int y = (int) points.get(i).getY();
            int x2 = (int) points.get(i + 1).getX();
            int y2 = (int) points.get(i + 1).getY();
            g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawingPanel(15));
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Using the above approach you will redraw the lines every time the component is repainted.

Another approach is to draw to a `BufferedImage` and then paint the `BufferedImage` on the panel. You can check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Gui programming and the cleard up a lot.I have two more questinos according to the code: 1.The `super.paintComomponent(g)` is used to basicly erase the drawn lines and set the background to white again right?. 2. If I wanted to be able to draw shapes when the mouse is clicked, I would need to modify the `repaint()`method (and ad a mouseListener) rigth?

Comment: I don't understand your question. All I can say is you would never change the repaint() method. I gave you a link to "Custom Painting Approaches". Read the link. It shows how to keep track of different shapes to paint.