# Problem drawing on JComponent via MouseMotionListener added to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, jcomponent

I want to draw ovals while dragging my mouse over a `JComponent` I added to a `JFrame`. I created two classes, one which extends `JComponent`, implements `MouseMotionListener` and overrides the paint(Graphics g) method, and another class with the main method in which I create a `JFrame` and add the `JComponent` to the frame. However, when I click and drag my mouse, nothing happens. I then added a default constructor to my `Painter` class and `addMouseMotionListener(this)` and `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));`, which made a black oval appear and follow my mouse pointer, deleting the previous ovals.

I have included the code for the two classes. Can anyone guide me on what could be wrong?
When I change `JComponent` to `JPanel` it works. Why does it not work this way with JComponent?

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class Painter extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener {
    private int x = -10;
    private int y = -10;
    
    public Painter() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    }   
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }   
    
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Painter painter = new Painter();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(painter);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're overriding `paint`.  You should be overriding `paintComponent`.  You should be using a `JPanel` for drawing.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: Did you try entering the following in the search box at the top of this webpage? [\[swing\] drag mouse draw oval](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+drag+mouse+draw+oval)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: It seems I completely forgot about this chapter of the tutorial and only remember that I clicked the link to the article but then left the chapter out. I think I'm not there yet to completely understand what's going on in the background. Thank you for the link, I will take my time to read all of this.

Comment: @Abra: I googled before considering posting here and after writing the comment viewed at the recommended postings before sending. Both the tutorial Gilbert Le Blanc  linked and your link point towards the invokeLater() method, I think the next step for me will be learning this and concurrency overall. Thank you very much!

Comment: The invokeLater() method, while important for understanding how Swing works, is not the cause of your painting problems. Read the Swing tutorial  on "Perfoming Custom Painting" to understand the correct way to do painting.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it not work this way with JComponent?

Actually it works correctly with JComponent.

The difference between the two components is that by default:

1. `JComponent` is non-opaque (transparent), which means the parent component will be painted first before the JComponent painting method is invoked and therefore the background is cleared so you only see a single oval.
2. `JPanel` is opaque, which means it is responsible for clearing the background first before doing the custom painting to prevent painting artifacts. You are not doing this.

What you are seeing is a painting artifact with the JPanel since the old painting is not removed.

Try drawing on the panel and then resize the frame and you will see all the ovals except the last one are removed.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52878359/131872 for one way to do the painting.